# Why isnt my rock papar scissors game working?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a rock paper scissor game to practice some fundamentals as I try to teach myself c++.
I had it working briefly, but I adjusted some of the cout content and now it is short circuiting some of the if statements. Any insights as to why this isn't working would be appreciated.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
```

game function. Requests input for player. Assigns variables random and guess to ints and then to strings result and result_2. Lastly the while loop tracks the score.

```
void Play_rps() {
    int guess;
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    std::string result;
    std::string result_2;
    std::cout << " Rock, Paper, Scissors. GO!! \n";
    while (i != 2 || o != 2) {

        int random = rand() % 4;
        std::cout << " 1.) Rock \n 2.) Paper \n 3.) Scissors \n";
        std::cin >> guess;

        switch (guess) {
        case 1:
            result = "rock";
            break;
        case 2:
            result = "paper";
            break;
        case 3:
            result = "scissors";
            break;

        }
        switch (random) {
        case 1:
            result_2 = "rock";
            break;
        case 2:
            result_2 = "paper";
            break;
        case 3:
            result_2 = "scissors";
            break;
        }
```

Nested if statements determine the out come of each round and increment the win counter.

```
        if (result == result_2) {

            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " TIE! \n" << std::endl;
        }
        else if (result == " rock" && result_2 == " paper") {
            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " Paper Beats Rock!\n You Lose! \n" << std::endl;
            o++;
        }
        else if (result == " paper" && result_2 == " rock") {
            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " Paper Beats Rock!\n You win! \n" << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
        else if (result == " scissors" && result_2 == " paper") {
            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " scissors Beat Paper!\n You Win! \n" << std::endl;
            i++;

        }
        else if (result == " rock" && result_2 == " scissors") {
            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " Rock Beats Scissors!\n You Win! \n" << std::endl;
            i++;
        }
        else if (result == " scissors" && result_2 == " rock") {
            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " Rock Beat Scissors! \n You lose! \n" << std::endl;
            o++;
        }
        else if (result == " paper" && result_2 == " scissors") {
            std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
            std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;
            std::cout << " scissors Beat Paper!\n You Lose! \n" << std::endl;
            o++;
        }

        if (i == 2) {
            std::cout << " YOU ARE VICTORIOUS \n";
        }
        else if (o == 2) {
            std::cout << " DEFEAT \n";
        }


    }
}
```

The main function is working properly as far as I can tell, but when I compile there is a warning about "t-time being an unsigned int, which may cause data to be lost" which is the only notification I get.

```
        int main()
         {
            srand(time(NULL));
            int choice;

            do {
                std::cout << "0.) Quit \n1.) Play Game \n";
                std::cin >> choice;

                switch (choice) {
                case 0:
                    std::cout << "Thanks for nothing! \n";
                    return 0;

                case 1:
                    Play_rps();
                    break;

                default:
                    std::cout << " That's not a valid choice. \n";
                }
            } while (choice != 0);
        }
```

Comment: Not likely the main problem, but with `while (i != 2 || o != 2)` you need to both win and lose to exit that loop! It should be &&. Or for more security against bugs, `while (i < 2 && o < 2)`

Comment: You have extra spaces in your == statements i.e " scissors" " papers"

Comment: You could avoid comparing strings by using named constants, e.g. `const int ROCK = 1;` and ``if ((result == ROCK) && (result2 == PAPER))`  You could convert the constants to text by using an array of text:  `char * names[] = {"", "rock", "paper", "scissors"};` and `std::cout << names[ROCK] << " " << names[result] << "\n";`

Comment: *I'm working on a rock paper scissor game to practice some fundamentals as I try to teach myself c++* -- Now is a good time to learn about `std::map` and `std::pair`, since this program could be done in about 5 lines of code if you had set it up using those containers.

Comment: [A small example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/61176ae8684e27c4)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the white spaces in the == statements and you can factorize some of your cout calls

```
    //" paper" --> "paper",  " rock" --> "rock"

    std::cout << " you threw " << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << " your opponant threw " << result_2 << std::endl;

    if (result == result_2) {
        std::cout << " TIE! \n" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (result == "rock" && result_2 == "paper") {
        std::cout << " Paper Beats Rock!\n You Lose! \n" << std::endl;
        o++;
    }
    else if (result == "paper" && result_2 == "rock") {
        std::cout << " Paper Beats Rock!\n You win! \n" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    else if (result == "scissors" && result_2 == "paper") {
        std::cout << " scissors Beat Paper!\n You Win! \n" << std::endl;
        i++;

    }
    else if (result == "rock" && result_2 == "scissors") {
        std::cout << " Rock Beats Scissors!\n You Win! \n" << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    else if (result == "scissors" && result_2 == "rock") {
        std::cout << " Rock Beat Scissors! \n You lose! \n" << std::endl;
        o++;
    }
    else if (result == "paper" && result_2 == "scissors") {
        std::cout << " scissors Beat Paper!\n You Lose! \n" << std::endl;
        o++;
    }
```